# Removing spaces to restructure an email address

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I am trying to restructure a text file that has email address to be compliant with email standards.

INPUT

```
fistname1 lastname1 <  email@domain1.com  >
fistname2 lastname2 othername2 <  email@domain2.com  >
fistname3 lastname3 could be more than one name <  email@domain3.com  >
```

desired output

```
fistname1 lastname1 <email@domain1.com>
fistname2 lastname2 othername2 <email@domain2.com>
fistname3 lastname3 could be more than one name <email@domain3.com>
```

I have tried some awk but it keeps failing.

Comment: So just to clarify, you want to remove the spaces between the `<` and the start of the email? (and the ending `>`?)

Comment: trying to remove all spaces between the < and the > ... thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `sed` you can do this:

```
sed -E 's/<[[:blank:]]*([^[:blank:]]+)[[:blank:]]*>/<\1>/g' file
```

```
fistname1 lastname1 <email@domain1.com>
fistname2 lastname2 othername2 <email@domain2.com>
fistname3 lastname3 could be more than one name <email@domain3.com>
```

**:: Command Details ::**

**Match:**

- `<`: Match `<`
- `[[:blank:]]*`: Match 0 or more whitespaces
- `([^[:blank:]]+)`: Match 1+ non-whitespace characters and capture in group #1
- `[[:blank:]]*`: Match 0 or more whitespaces
- `>`: Match `>`

**Replacement:**

- `<\1>`: Replace with back-reference of group #1 wrapped with `<` and `>`

Answer (score 0):

Try it with `sed`'s `-E`xtended pattern matching. Easier to read.

```
sed -E 's/<\s+/</; s/\s+>/>/;' file
fistname1 lastname1 <email@domain1.com>
fistname2 lastname2 othername2 <email@domain2.com>
fistname3 lastname3 could be more than one name <email@domain3.com>
```

If it's a really big file, you might save a little time doing it all in one pattern

```
sed -E 's/<\s*(\S+)\s*>/<\1>/;' file
```

(As an aside, I have decided that I, too, shall name my fists. ;)

Comment: This will break if the whitespace isn't next to the `<>`'s, though.